# Programmatically close alert() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm trying to trigger an alert close once an event happens. Currently I get a popup when the internet cuts out (I want that). But once the connection is reestablished, I want the popup to automatically go away - not having to hit exit or OK.

I have this code:

```
 setInterval(function(){
if(navigator.onLine){
    ( ".selector" ).popup( "close" );
}else{
    window.alert("It seems you have lost connection to the internet. 
Please reconnect before continuing.");
}},2000);
```

Thanks

Comment: quick answer: not possible; create your own HTML-based popups.

Comment: you have no control over the browser dialog boxes (alert, prompt, confirm, etc.), you need to create your own via HTML

Comment: Check out how jsfiddle does it: http://jsfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot close the javascript's `alert();` by code. You can try to use alternative notification method like modal window or something (so then if user is back online you can simply use jQuery function to hide/remove the modal box).

Answer (score 3):

According to my knowledge Java Script Alert box cant be change or close programmatically. So you can use [Jquery UI Dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)  or [bootstrap model](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals) or something else.