# Auto Closing MessageBox controls

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to use VB.NET to close MessageBox controls created by JavaScript in VB.NET webbrowser?
I do not want to disable JavaScript in the webbrowser, just to close the MessageBox controls (like clicking their "X" button). I could not get help from search engines. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Vb.net` is serverside and rendered before `javascript` as the `javascript` is client side and rendered on browser. So there is not such way closing alert pop up via server side code.

Neither it is possible via jquery on client side

Comment: Then is it possible to close other application's MessageBox from VB.NET?

Comment: I am also thinking probably, if there is a way to detect that a MessageBox is opened, then VB.NET could click "enter" to close it; correct?

Comment: Nope, if such action is possible this could be done via javascript. However as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485086/programmatically-close-alert-in-javascript) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466802/how-can-i-auto-hide-alert-box-after-it-showing-it), that is not possible